# Material Design Lite blocks my tooltip from showing

Tags: tooltip

the mdl class mdl-layout__content is blocking my tooltip from showing in my graph. I made a codepen that shows the problem.  Are there style settings I can make to still use this class for my nav, but show my tooltip.

[Link to CodePen that shows the issue](https://codepen.io/brbeardm/pen/JJaaPY?editors=1000)

here's my HTML code

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="A front-end template that helps you build fast, modern mobile web apps.">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

    <title>New UI 07052017</title>
    <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Material Design Lite
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.orange-indigo.min.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.orange-indigo.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">      
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.indigo-pink.min.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angular-toggle-switch-bootstrap-3.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-material-design.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael-min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script> **** updated to 1.6.1 on 6/29/17-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.0/firebase.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.6/firebase.js"></script>

    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.1/angularfire.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/angular-toggle-switch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angularScripts.js"></script>

    <!-- JustGage tools for the dashboard -->
    <script src="js/justgage.js"></script>


    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/android-icon-192x192.png">

    <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Pellet Pirate">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/apple-icon-114x114.png">

    <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144 + tile color) -->
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/pelletpirate-icon-32x32.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.0/material.cyan-light_blue.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <!-- Import and configure the Firebase SDK -->
    <!-- These scripts are made available when the app is served or deployed on Firebase Hosting -->
    <!-- If you do not serve/host your project using Firebase Hosting see https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/4.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/4.0.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

    <style>
        #view-source {
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        z-index: 900;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body ng-app="PelletPirate">
        <div class="demo-layout mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header">
        <header class="demo-header mdl-layout__header mdl-color--grey-100 mdl-color-text--grey-600">
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                <span class="mdl-layout-title">smoker</span>
                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
                        <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="search">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                        </label>
                        <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search">
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search">Enter your query...</label>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--icon" id="hdrbtn">
                        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="demo-drawer mdl-layout__drawer mdl-color--blue-grey-900 mdl-color-text--blue-grey-50">
                <header class="demo-drawer-header">




                </header>
                <nav class="demo-navigation mdl-navigation mdl-color--blue-grey-800">
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">whatshot</i>Manage a Cook</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">inbox</i>Inbox</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">delete</i>Trash</a>
                    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">help_outline</i>
                    <span class="visuallyhidden">Help</span></a>
                </nav>
        </div>







<!-- *********************************************************************************************************************-->

<!-- need help here. I'm not sure what settings to make in CSS to enable the tooltip popup to show. If I comment out the  -->
<!-- the mdl-layout__content class then the tooltips show but my graph now drifts left behind my left nav -->

<!-- *********************************************************************************************************************-->

        <main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
        <!-- <main class="mdl-color--grey-100"> -->


            <div class="mdl-grid demo-content">

                <div class="demo-graphs mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-color--white mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col">

                    <div class="plot-container">
                        <div id="temp-placeholder" class="plot-placeholder"></div>
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="row" id="ControlsRow">
                    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
                        <div class="plot-container">
                            <div id="controls-placeholder" class="plot-placeholder"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

            <footer class="mdl-mini-footer">
                <div class="mdl-mini-footer--middle-section">
                    <div class="mdl-logo">"It's a Pirate's life for me."</div>
                    <ul class="mdl-mini-footer--link-list">
                        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy & Terms</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyD3_xJ0aYVK3VwjuuliOdb6t5wbbi87RB8",
    authDomain: "pelletpirate.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://pelletpirate.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "pelletpirate",
    storageBucket: "pelletpirate.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "731610976061"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var Ref = firebase.database().ref()
</script>

<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/Cscripts.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:  z-index to bring the tooltip to the forefront. In CSS:

```
#tooltip {
  z-index: 1;
}
```